# Insert rows into a temp table having one and only one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table with one and only one column called Id. How can I insert 100 rows into this table with the most minimal query?

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I already tagged it. Its SQL server.

Comment: Are the 100 rows in another table?

Comment: @VDK No, I want to insert into the same table itslef. Would be better if we can avoid duplicationg insert into statements also. The most optimized query is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky.  A brute force method is to turn off identity insert:

```
set identity_insert #Sample on;

with n as (
      select 1 as n union all
      select n + 1
      from n
      where n + 1 <= 100
     )
insert into #Sample(id)
    select n.n
    from n;

set identity_insert #Sample off;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @i int = 1

while(@i<=100)
begin
insert into #Sample default values
set @i=@i+1
end

select * from #Sample
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Default values and use batch seperator go to execute insert 100 times

```
insert into #sample
default values
go 100
```